# Xcode 10.2 Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating Xcode 8 to Xcode 10 the apps are not running in simulator. And I am getting this error.

[image: ss1]

Comment: Try by cleaning build folder and rebuilding your project. If that doesn't work, relaunch Xcode, clean build folder and rebuild. It that too fails, try by deleting derived data folder.

Comment: Things to try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635861/unable-to-contact-local-dtservicehub-to-bless-simulator-connection.